# IBM Worklight - Is there a Window.open() equivalent?

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, window.open

I searched the WL API in the Information Center but didn't find a WL equivalent API to the Cordova window.open() which will open the URL in an in app browser (using the _blank option for example).

Does one exist or should I just use the cordova API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[WL.App.openURL](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/apiref/r_opening_urls.html) is an implementation of what you are looking for it. Underlying it is Cordova.

Though, Window.open() has some advantages. I have [a writeup comparing different ways of opening server side pages](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/dhuyvett/entry/including_external_content_in_a_worklight_application1?lang=en).

Comment: So I guess the answer is no.  There is no equivalent.  The WL open opens in the system browser.  I sued the cordova one in this scenario.